# AlertDialog.setButton crashes my app

Tags: android

As the title says, when I put a .setButton to my alert dialog, my app crashes.
What is the problem and how should I fix it?

```
button_fs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_fs);
    final AlertDialog adfs = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    button_fs.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            adfs.setTitle("Meraxes");
            adfs.setMessage("What would you like to do?");
            adfs.setButton(1, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Aww yiss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            adfs.setButton(2, "cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you have pressed cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            adfs.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: `setButton()`... don't you mean `setPositiveButton()` and `setNegativeButton()`, instead??

Comment: I found the answer just after I posted this. Thanks for the quick response, by the way.

Comment: I used "DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE" instead of "1" in 
adfs.setButton(1, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()